# Stop Python from Opening Interactive Console on Script Quit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, python-3.6

I've had an issue, more of a nuisance, with python 3.6 specifically that I cant find an answer to after searching for it, and thinking I would be clever by looking for a python config file.

Whenever I run a script and that script quits, my command line pops open with an interactive console for that script, even though I've added `exit(); quit()` and tried just `quit()` to my script. I don't want to be forced to type quit() into the CLI every time I run my script. Is there a way to disable this functionality of Python?

Comment: can you share the script? Or at least a minimal example that exhibits this behavior? If it isn't your code, `os.environ['PYTHONINSPECT']` might have been set. Also, how are you running Python? Do you pass the `-i` option?